# no local server type "database engine" were found (V 2016)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016-localdb

I don't know many things about **SQL server**, today I install the **SQL Server Management Studio 2016** and want to create a local Database. after search in the internet find this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345332(v=sql.110).aspx) from **microsoft**. in step 4 of this tutorial found this error when want to **regester local servers**

> no local server type "database engine" were found

witch part is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**SQL Server Management Studio 2016** (as name says) contains **Only** SQL Server Management Studio that just GUI for managing any SQL infrastructure.

**Form MSDN:-**

> SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) is an integrated environment for
>   managing any SQL infrastructure, from SQL Server to SQL Database. SSMS
>   provides tools to configure, monitor, and administer instances of SQL
>   from wherever you deploy it. SSMS provides tools to deploy, monitor,
>   and upgrade the data-tier components, such as databases and data
>   warehouses used by your applications, and to build queries and
>   scripts.

Look at the downloads at the [official download website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express).
**under** *Try SQL Server 2016 SP1 Express for free* **click** *Get started* button.

Comment: you right, my colleague give me the wrong file to install and I didn't attention to the file name.

Answer (score 2):

Open command prompt as admin 
-> sqllocaldb info  (which gets your local databases) 
-> sqllocaldb versions (which gets your right version to be installed with your local db server) 
-> sqllocaldb create "Your db Name" version name given if you find it (This creates a local db engine) 
-> In SSMS Server Name : (LocalDb)\Your db Name

This should solve your sql server 2018 or other versions initial setup of local server db engine issue.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me while installing SSMS 2022.

In older versions there was an optional check that now is missing to directly install SQL Server together.

In the current version, this doesn't exist, and it does not install it automatically.

After finishing installing SQL Server, it will result in a prompt to install SSMS, so apparently they interchanged the order.

To verify exactly what you need to install to be compatible with your SSMS, open a command prompt and run command `sqllocaldb versions`.